# How to use if syntax & will result output twice?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub test()
    LastRow_Sheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    LastRow_Sheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count

For x = 2 To 30

    po_number = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 1).Value
    site_name = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 2).Value

    For y = 2 To LastRow_Sheet2
        If po_number <> Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, 1).Value Then ' And (InStr(1, Cells(y, 30), CStr(site_name)) >= 1) Then
            With Worksheets("Sheet2")
            If InStr(1, .Cells(y, 30), CStr(site_name)) >= 1 Then
                .Range(.Cells(y, 1), .Cells(y, 31)).Copy
                nextRow = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Sheets("Sheet3").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & nextRow).PasteSpecial
            End If
          End With
        End If
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

Hi All,

Question 1, will these two `if syntax` have same result ?

```
If po_number <> Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, 1).Value And (InStr(1, Cells(y, 30), CStr(site_name)) >= 1) Then
            With Worksheets("Sheet2")
            .Range(.Cells(y, 1), .Cells(y, 31)).Copy
                nextRow = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Sheets("Sheet3").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & nextRow).PasteSpecial
            End With
    End If

If po_number <> Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, 1).Value Then
         With Worksheets("Sheet2")
            If InStr(1, .Cells(y, 30), CStr(site_name)) >= 1 Then
                .Range(.Cells(y, 1), .Cells(y, 31)).Copy
                nextRow = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Sheets("Sheet3").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & nextRow).PasteSpecial
            End If
          End With
        End If
```

Question 2, It seems that my original code will output the result twice .. could anyone help me to define that?

Many thanks ..

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: @a-burge how do u mean data?